# What was the composition of the primordial asteroid belt?

Tags: asteroid-belt

According to one theory, the region between Mars and Jupiter was once populated by several primordial planets with a combined mass of roughly the earth.  These planets provided the material that made up the original asteroid belt.  Since then, 99.9% of this material was lost.  The current composition of the asteroid belt is about 10% metallic and 90% silicate/carbonaceous.  Could we assume that the original asteroid belt had the same composition?  Or, at least a very similar composition?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that theory?  Or at least an epoch it was supposed to happen in? I guess it'd predate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_tack_hypothesis

Comment: There was a planet there that exploded. That's the most plausible theory and it's supported by math (based on current planetary orbit distances).

Comment: @Overmind no, that’s a myth. Regarding the math, Bode’s Law was discredited long ago.

Comment: If you consider Neptune to be the 'first' Kuiper belt object, then the law is correct. You must take SBOs into account, not only planets.

Answer (score -2):

We can be pretty sure that the asteroid belt once held one or more sizable planetesimals,as there is evidence that it or they were large enough for gravity & internal heating to drag the heavy metals (mainly iron & nickel) to the centre,forming a metallic core. Bodes Law decrees that there should be a planet where the asteroid belt is now,but it seems that as this planet was forming it was shattered by an impact & the remnants scattered. Some reached Earth,which is how we know that their materials had differentiated into metallic core & rocky mantle. It is likely that some of the huge asteroids which have struck the Earth in the distant past were fragments thrown out of the asteroid belt & that some hit Mars & Venus as well. There may be more material in the asteroid belt than we think,because some fragments are so small & widely dispersed that they don't register in our telescopes. I think we can assume that the primordial planetesimals had a similar though not identical composition to the asteroid belt of today.